# Julia gives "MethodError: rand!" when trying to optimize over a certain manifold using Manopt

Tags: optimization, random, julia

My goal is to find the minimum of a certain function over the manifold of doubly stochastic matrices. I use the package Manopt (https://manoptjl.org/stable/) for this. The relevant part of my code looks like this:

```
using Random
using Graphs
using Manopt
using Manifolds
using LinearAlgebra

n = 8
G = DiGraph(n)
for i = 1:n
    add_edge!(G, i%n +1, (i+1)%n +1)
    add_edge!(G, (i+1)%n +1, i%n +1)
end

A = adjacency_matrix(G)
P_0 = A / 2
M = MultinomialMatrices(n, n)
f(M, p) = 0 #sum((P_0 - p).^ 2)

particle_swarm(M, f)
```

Of course I need to change f to a more complex function, however, the code is not even working in this case of f=0. I also tried using the Nelder Mead Method instead of the partical swarm, yielding the same error. The error is the following: "MethodError: rand!(::TaskLocalRNG, ::AbstractManifold, ::SubArray{Float64, 1, Matrix{Float64}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Int64}, true}) is ambiguous. Candidates: [...]" and it keeps on listing 50-70 candidates.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I tried using different manifolds to optimize over and the problem didn't occur in the case of "simpler" one (eg. the sphere). I tried using other methods for optimizing, none of them worked.

Comment: My searches found a missing `rand` implementation for `ProbabilitySimplex`, which is in the works in https://github.com/JuliaManifolds/Manifolds.jl/pull/604 .

Comment: Was this clarified somewhen? On my machine this works (on the current versions of Manifolds.jl and Manopt.jl).

Comment: It seems to be working now, thank you. However, it produces the same error if I use MultinomialSymmetric or MultinomialDoubleStochastic, so I hope this will be solved soon.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an MWE? Maybe open an issue with `Manifolds.jl` and we take a look and fix it :) Manopt sometimes assumes that a few functions are implemented. Usually the “Technical Details” section of a solver should clarify which ones are expected. If they are not implemented for a manifold in `Manifolds.jl` open an issue there and we check what we can do.

Comment: I took a short look at `MultinomialDoubleStochastic` and `MultinomialSymmetric ` can confirm that that one has not generation for random points. The simple reason is, that I am not aware of a reference for that (and without a formula, my magic is limited). If you provide a random point generator formula for any of them, I am happy to do a PR to Manifolds.jl to add them.

Comment: Since the paper https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8861409 lists possibilities (to be precise they are isometrically embedded) I opened a PR https://github.com/JuliaManifolds/Manifolds.jl/pull/702. Might take a bit, still, though. I try to find time soon

Comment: Thank you very much Ronny for your time spent with this. (We would primarily use MultinomialSymmetric in our research.)

Comment: You're welcome – if I find time I usually try to extend the manifolds and functions. If you check the PR, I did most testing and documentation yesterday, there are just a few boundary cases left. I can let you know here once this is merged.

Comment: That would be awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind the initial error (and the follow ups in the comments) is relatively simple.

The algorithms from [Manopt.jl](https://manoptjl.org/stable/) follow the [ManifoldsBase.jl](https://juliamanifolds.github.io/ManifoldsBase.jl/stable/) “interface” of a typical manifold and expect a certain set of functions for a specific manifold to be implemented.
For often includes for example a retraction. Details are usually documented on the [Technical Details](https://manoptjl.org/stable/solvers/particle_swarm/#sec-arc-technical-details) section for every solver, like the one in the question here [particle swarm](https://manoptjl.org/stable/solvers/particle_swarm/).
For now the technical details do not mention `rand`/`rand!`, since that is not necessarily needed for the algorithm itself, but just for the initialisation of default values (in any algorithm actually). One could maybe improve that.

Sometimes these functions are not all implemented in Manifolds.jl, either because no one came along yet needing them, or (more likely) because  the people implementing a certain manifold were not aware of a formula / paper / reference for there. For example the exponential map is not available in closed form on certain manifolds (though then several retractions usually still are).

For the specific manifolds at hand, I took a peek into literature and noticed that the `rand` functions could actually be provided from what is given in literature, e.g.

- for [MultinomialSymmetric](https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/manifolds/multinomialsymmetric.html#Base.rand-Tuple%7BMultinomialSymmetric%7D)
- for [MultinomialDoubleStochastic](https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/manifolds/multinomialdoublystochastic.html#Base.rand-Tuple%7BMultinomialDoubleStochastic%7D)
- and even for a new manifold I could easily add, [MultinomialSymmetricPositiveDefinite](https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/manifolds/multinomialsymmetricpositivedefinite.html#Random.rand!-Tuple%7BRandom.AbstractRNG,%20MultinomialSymmetricPositiveDefinite,%20AbstractMatrix%7D), where we could maybe move the doc string also and attach it to `rand` (which by default uses `rand!` internally)

All these are now thoroughly tested, documented, and available in the new [Manifolds.jl](https://juliamanifolds.github.io/Manifolds.jl/stable/index.html) version 0.9.13.